# jquery append foreach to div

Tags: jquery, keyword, tag-cloud

I'm trying to create a dynamic tag cloud using jquery, I want it to pull the keywords from the page and then spit them out in a div, but am not sure how to go about it - I know how I could do it if it were php, but just not so good at jquery.

I've created my variable "keywords"

```
var keywords = jQuery("meta[name=keywords]").attr("content");
```

Now how do I go about doing a foreach for it to append the div "tagCloud" like this:

```
<div class="tagCloud" id="tagCloud">

  Keyword 1 \n
  Keyword 2 \n
  Keyword 3 \n

</div>
```

and so forth.. if someone could help me, that'd be fantastic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the cloud keywords to be links (anchors):

```
$($('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content').split(',')).each(function(i, el) {
    $('#tagCloud').append($('<a>').attr('href','#').text(el));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this :

```
   var all = "";
    jQuery("meta[name=keywords]").each(function(){
      all += jQuery(this).attr("content") + "\n";
    });
    jQuery("#tagCloud").html(all);
```